# React Autodesk Forge Create Buckets

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to create a bucket from the front end of a react app, once I work this out I will make the requests through the backend. I am passing in an options object inside of the useEffect hook and logging the result to the console. The headers are returning undefined on the environment variables I have passed in from a .env.I would like to know how do I pass in the headers from the .env or hard code for now? I aslo need to pass in scope into the headers bucket:create, bucket: read

Buckets.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Buckets = () => {
useEffect(() => {
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate',
  headers: {
    ContentType: 'application/json',
    Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_FORGE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_FORGE_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.REACT_APP_FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  },
}
console.log(options)
}, [])

return <div>Buckets</div>
}
```

export default Buckets

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the code snippet:

- first of all, you should *never* expose the client secret to the browser; implementing bucket creation on the server side is pretty straightforward
- second, the `process.env` construct you use in your code is a Node.js feature, not something that's available in browser; that's most likely why the headers end up being empty

So with that, I would just suggest that you implement any of the Forge requests on the server side (for example, by following https://learnforge.autodesk.io), and then expose that functionality to your React frontend via a couple of endpoints.

EDIT: as mentioned in the comments, I'm working on "unofficial Forge SDK for Node.js", and that library does have an experimental support for browsers. Try something like this:

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/forge-server-utils/dist/browser/forge-server-utils.js"></script>
    <script>
        const client = new forge.DataManagementClient({ client_id: '...', client_secret: '...' });
        client.listBuckets()
            .then(buckets => { console.log('Buckets', buckets); })
            .catch(err => { console.error('Could not get buckets', err); });
    </script>
```

Comment: AI mentioned I was going to move the client secret to the backend once I had this working and according to the cra documentation you can declare environment varilabes https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/.

Comment: sorry I hit the enter button. Hi Petr, As mentioned I was going to move the client secret to the backend once I had this working and according to the cra documentation you can declare environment variables https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/. Anyway, I was able to get the requests working from the backend in postman but now I want to replicate this from my react frontend. Are there any examples of how to implement this? There are plenty of examples showing the viewer but not buckets or the objects in the buckets.

Comment: Since this is not a good practice (and it's a potential security risk), we don't really provide/promote samples for implementing this.

Comment: I do have an experimental support for browsers in my "unofficial Forge SDK for Node.js": https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-server-utils#client-side-experimental. But that one assumes that you already have an access token generated through other means. I'm not sure if you'll be able to generate a new token by passing in the client ID and secret. In that case you may start running into other issues, e.g., [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).